Measuring black box code coverage in xcode
I am trying to measure code coverage for an iOS app on xcode. Is there any way to measure this?
Everything that I have seen online mentions opening the scheme editor and turning on code coverage but this only captures the coverage of unit tests. Is there currently a way to measure black box coverage with manual usage of the application?
